# Minify Javascript programmatically in-memory

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, coffeescript, minify

I am building a nifty little "asset-pipeline" for a express.js application, but i have a problem with the compression-step for javascript files

```
scripts = (fs.readFileSync(file) for file in filelist)
result = scripts.join("\n\n") # concat
```

upto now, things are working as expected (the logic itself is written in coffeescript). The next step after merging the JS-files would be to minify them. But here is my problem: i want to do this "hot" when i start my express-app in production mode, from within a piece of connect-middleware i wrote.

I need a solution that can minify a given blob of javascript stuff, *without writing the result to disk* (!), in other words: a function that does the minification and returns the result directly as a result value. (No, *no webservices* either.) It should be usable like this:

```
minified_result = awesomeMinifyFunction( result )
```

The raw processing performance isn't *that* important for me, neither is the level of compression, i need just something that works this way without hassle.

Does anyone know a suitable solution? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'd suggest you look at one of the JavaScript based minifiers, like [UglifyJS2](https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS2).

```
npm install uglify-js
```

It can be used within a Node.JS application programatically:

```
var UglifyJS = require("uglify-js");
// you could pass multiple files (rather than reading them as strings)
var result = UglifyJS.minify([ "file1.js", "file2.js", "file3.js" ]);
console.log(result.code);
```

Or you could

```
var result = scripts.join("\n\n");  # concat
result = UglifyJS.minify(result, {fromString: true});
console.log(result.code);
```

Comment: alright, it just works. I didn't saw their programming-api the first time.

Answer (score 0):

You can write your own function that removes all comments/spaces/blank lines etc.

You can use a regular expression that makes use of [rJSmin](http://opensource.perlig.de/rjsmin/) like:

```
function awesomeMinifyFunction(result)
{
   pattern = (
    r'([^\047"/\000-\040]+)|((?:(?:\047[^\047\\\r\n]*(?:\\(?:[^\r\n]|\r?'
    r'\n|\r)[^\047\\\r\n]*)*\047)|(?:"[^"\\\r\n]*(?:\\(?:[^\r\n]|\r?\n|'
    r'\r)[^"\\\r\n]*)*"))[^\047"/\000-\040]*)|(?<=[(,=:\[!&|?{};\r\n])(?'
    r':[\000-\011\013\014\016-\040]|(?:/\*[^*]*\*+(?:[^/*][^*]*\*+)*/))*'
    r'(?:(?:(?://[^\r\n]*)?[\r\n])(?:[\000-\011\013\014\016-\040]|(?:/\*'
    r'[^*]*\*+(?:[^/*][^*]*\*+)*/))*)*((?:/(?![\r\n/*])[^/\\\[\r\n]*(?:('
    r'?:\\[^\r\n]|(?:\[[^\\\]\r\n]*(?:\\[^\r\n][^\\\]\r\n]*)*\]))[^/\\\['
    r'\r\n]*)*/)[^\047"/\000-\040]*)|(?<=[\000-#%-,./:-@\[-^`{-~-]return'
    r')(?:[\000-\011\013\014\016-\040]|(?:/\*[^*]*\*+(?:[^/*][^*]*\*+)*/'
    r'))*(?:(?:(?://[^\r\n]*)?[\r\n])(?:[\000-\011\013\014\016-\040]|(?:'
    r'/\*[^*]*\*+(?:[^/*][^*]*\*+)*/)))*((?:/(?![\r\n/*])[^/\\\[\r\n]*(?'
    r':(?:\\[^\r\n]|(?:\[[^\\\]\r\n]*(?:\\[^\r\n][^\\\]\r\n]*)*\]))[^/'
    r'\\\[\r\n]*)*/)[^\047"/\000-\040]*)|(?<=[^\000-!#%&(*,./:-@\[\\^`{|'
    r'~])(?:[\000-\011\013\014\016-\040]|(?:/\*[^*]*\*+(?:[^/*][^*]*\*+)'
    r'*/))*(?:((?:(?://[^\r\n]*)?[\r\n]))(?:[\000-\011\013\014\016-\040]'
    r'|(?:/\*[^*]*\*+(?:[^/*][^*]*\*+)*/))*)+(?=[^\000-\040"#%-\047)*,./'
    r':-@\\-^`|-~])|(?<=[^\000-#%-,./:-@\[-^`{-~-])((?:[\000-\011\013\01'
    r'4\016-\040]|(?:/\*[^*]*\*+(?:[^/*][^*]*\*+)*/)))+(?=[^\000-#%-,./:'
    r'-@\[-^`{-~-])|(?<=\+)((?:[\000-\011\013\014\016-\040]|(?:/\*[^*]*'
    r'\*+(?:[^/*][^*]*\*+)*/)))+(?=\+)|(?<=-)((?:[\000-\011\013\014\016-'
    r'\040]|(?:/\*[^*]*\*+(?:[^/*][^*]*\*+)*/)))+(?=-)|(?:[\000-\011\013'
    r'\014\016-\040]|(?:/\*[^*]*\*+(?:[^/*][^*]*\*+)*/))+|(?:(?:(?://[^'
    r'\r\n]*)?[\r\n])(?:[\000-\011\013\014\016-\040]|(?:/\*[^*]*\*+(?:[^'
    r'/*][^*]*\*+)*/))*)+'
)
 return result.match(pattern);
}
```

Comment: Nice approach, but after re-formatting to valid coffeescript, i realized that octal's in JS-regexps are forbidden (coffeescript uses strict mode).

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend taking a look at Asset Rack, which already implements what you're building.

Comment: i looked at it seriously, but i want a specific and high-performance behavior. in fact, none of the current asset-pipelines are working the way i want them to.